# How to access variable value in Docker command when user passes command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, subprocess

```py
import sys
import os
import subprocess
        
app_name = sys.argv[1]
s = subprocess.call(
    "docker ps --filter name=$app_name| awk '{print $2}' > docker_tag.txt",
    shell=True
)
```

How can I access the value of the variable inside `subprocess.call()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `f` string

**Ex:**

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

app_name=sys.argv[1]
s=subprocess.call(['docker', 'ps', '--filter', f"name={app_name}", '|', 'awk', "'{print", "$2}'", '>', 'docker_tag.txt'], shell=True)
# OR
#s=subprocess.call(f"docker ps --filter name={app_name}| awk '{print $2}' > docker_tag.txt", shell=True)
```

Comment: getting  syntax error when do use above code
[centos@exe93-aws-mum:/exedge-volume/exedge]# python test.py  upf-fpm
  File "test.py", line 6
    s=subprocess.call(['docker', 'ps', '--filter', f"name={app_name}", '|', 'awk', "'{print", "$2}'", '>', 'docker_tag.txt'], shell=True)
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: is your Python version 3.6 and above?

Comment: [centos@exe93-aws-mum:~]# python3 --version
Python 3.6.8